# How to create a dummy variable in R with multiple conditions using ifelse() command

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dummy variable in R where the categorical variable "position" equals 1 for 'first base' or 'second base'. I know how to do this with only one like 'first base' but I'm not sure how to do it including second base as option. How would I write this code?

```
baseball$POS <- ifelse(baseballdf$position == "first base", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` if we are matching multiple elements and also, `ifelse` is not needed as `TRUE/FALSE` can be coerced to 1/0 with `as.integer` or `+`

```
as.integer(baseballdf$position %in% c("first base", "second base"))
```